# Persistent action when routing in Backbone?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, backbone.js, url-routing

I have a number of parts of my web application routed in Backbone. All rendered items are inside the main body in the html, and there are a few items in the header that change depending on where the user is navigating to (or from).

This is all fine, however, controlling these dynamic changes requires some redundant code. Is it possible to add an action when routing that always triggers? A use case for this, for example, could be pushing a loading icon to the screen between renders.

Not looking for a default action (when no route is define), but a persistent action that triggers with every new navigation.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could bind every route change in the router to a function.
Just add this in the `initializer/constructor` method of your Router:

```
initialize: function() {
  this.on('all', this.routeChanged, this)
},

routeChanged: function(route) {
  // perform repeating tasks here
}
```

Comment: Ah, that's exactly what I was looking for! Didn't put the two and two together, but of course, event binders in Backbone are available throughout the MVC, right? Thanks!

Comment: You should award people that have helped you upvoting and/or accepting their answers.

Comment: I think it is worth mentioning that the `"all"` event is a general feature of `Backbone.Events` (http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Events-on) so it works with all event-ish things in Backbone.